# Unable to evaluate math expressions using Mathos Math Prser

Tags: javascript, c#, parsing, math, evaluation

I am using [Mathos Math parser](http://mathosparser.codeplex.com/) to evaluate math expressions. I am trying to parse following expression but it throws FormatException - Input string was not in a correct format..

```
Mathos.Parser.MathParser parser = new Mathos.Parser.MathParser();
string expression = "Math.pow((4),(5))"; //Or "Math.sqrt(1)";
string result = parser.Parse(expression).ToString();
```

In my app I am using [MathDox](http://mathdox.org/formulaeditor/) mathml editor, which gives me mathml. Using this mathml I am parsing it to plain math expression using javascript as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26357109/parsing-mathml-to-plain-math-expression/#answer-26386993) and then sending this expression to my c# code for evaluation.
Whats wrong in my expression.

**Note:** Due to certain conditions I am not evaluating the math expression in javascript.

Comment: One solution I fond is to use javascript eval in c# using Microsoft Jscript instead of Mathos. http://odetocode.com/articles/80.aspx But it also fails in some cases

Comment: could you please check whether my solution worked!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it does not work is because the *pow* function is defined as a localFunction. The code below should work:

```
Mathos.Parser.MathParser parser = new Mathos.Parser.MathParser();
string expression = "pow(4,5)"; 
string result = parser.Parse(expression).ToString();

// or

string expression2 = "4^5"; 
string result2 = parser.Parse(expression2).ToString();

Assert.AreEqual(result, result2);
```

Basically, in order to use the Math.Pow function, you either use the *build in power operator* or the *built in power function*.

You can change the definition of the power function at any time. This is the current defiinition:

1. Power function: `LocalFunctions.Add("pow", x => (decimal)Math.Pow((double)x[0], (double)x[1]));`
2. Power operator: `OperatorList.Add("^");`  and `OperatorAction.Add("^", (numberA, numberB) => (decimal)Math.Pow((double)numberA, (double)numberB));`